# XBee3 Coordinator cannot find End_Device during Network Discovery

Tags: xbee, zigbee, micropython

Currently, I am running XBee3 International Mesh Kit and tried following the given example in the documentation.

https://www.digi.com/resources/documentation/Digidocs/90001942-13/?utm_source=packaging&utm_medium=insert&utm_campaign=xbee3&utm_content=XBeeZigbeeMeshKit#tasks/t_configure_zigbee_modules.htm%3FTocPath%3DGetting%2520started%2520with%2520XBee%2520Zigbee%7CExample%253A%2520basic%2520communication%7C_____4

I tried implementing the Network Discovery for the three devices using Micropython REPL.

The following is the configuration I have for my 3 XBee devices.
[Parameters for the 3 XBee Devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Uxws.png)

I am running the following code on the Coordinator and End-Device for network discovery
https://www.digi.com/resources/documentation/digidocs/90001539/#reference/r_node_discovery_micropython.htm%3FTocPath%3DGet%2520started%2520with%2520MicroPython%7CMicroPython%

Now when I try to run the python code for Network discovery on the Coordinator (XBee_A), it does not find any End-Device in the node list. The only Router comes up in the search.

But when I run it on the End-Device, it does find the Coordinator and Router.

My idea was to get the details of the End-Device using network discovery, gets it network ID (NI) and then send a command to the device.

Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: That Digi user guide is practically useless.  I ran into the exact same issue in 2021 and they don't bother fixing their documentation.  Have you figure out a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried going into command mode and executing an `ATND`?  What are your sleep parameters?  If the end device is sleeping longer than the node discovery time limit, it won't be awake to respond to the discovery broadcast.

Try reducing the sleep duration on the end device, or increasing the node discovery timeout (`ATNT`) on the Coordinator.

Comment: Increasing the Node Discovery timeout worked for me.

Comment: I can't even get two coordinators or coordinator+router both connected to the machine with default setting to discover each other in the network.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue where the coordinator just couldn't discover any node in the same network. Spending hours digging through other documentations and just to sadly realize the updated XCTU has both DH and DL defaulted to 0 so the default dash for DL in [Digi's Mesh Kit User Guide](https://www.digi.com/resources/documentation/Digidocs/90001942-13/?utm_source=packaging&utm_medium=insert&utm_campaign=xbee3&utm_content=XBeeZigbeeMeshKit#tasks/t_configure_zigbee_modules.htm?TocPath=Get%2520started%2520with%2520XBee%2520Zigbee%257CExample%253A%2520basic%2520communication%257C_____4) should manually be set to FFFF instead for the coordinator to work. Not the best documentation and there are quite a few errors and information missing out then leave you guessing or pay them for support.