# How can I find my end devices in my zigbee network with a python script?

Tags: python, xbee, zigbee

Im trying o discover all the devices in my zigbee network through a programable XBee board with a python script. For that I use:

```
xnet = xbee.get_network()
xnet.start_discovery_process()
while xnet.is_discovery_running():
    time.sleep(0.5)
devices = xnet.get_devices()
```

the problem is that It only finds the routers and the coordinator but it doesnt find any End device. Is there any way to get ALL the devices in the network?

Thanks

Comment: What's the sleep cycle for the end devices?  Is it possible to run the discovery process longer than the default time, to allow those end devices to wake up and respond?  Behind the scenes it's doing an `ATND` to discover the nodes, so you could read up on the XBee documentation for that feature.

Comment: I have tried running for longer time the discovery process but it didnt worked. I thought that maybe the devices dont appear beacuse the device in which I do the discovery process is  a router and not the coordinator. How could I ask to the coordinator from a router to make a network discovery?

Comment: Discovery from either router or coordinator should be identical.  You need to increase `ATNT` on the device performing discovery, perhaps to its maximum value of 0xFF (25.5 seconds) and make sure the end device sleep cycle is short enough to respond.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [XBee3 Coordinator cannot find End\_Device during Network Discovery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55003082/xbee3-coordinator-cannot-find-end-device-during-network-discovery)

Comment: I've done that (increasing ATND on the device to the maximum value) and the device sleep cycle is 12 seconds but it didnt worked. Im sure that the end device is in the network because when I use XCTU it appears in there but when I use the python library and the get_network() function doesnt appear.

Comment: (I assume you meant increasing ATNT.)  Does XCTU have a log that would show the commands it's sending?  That could help.  You could also try lowering the end device sleep cycle significantly just to get node discovery working, and then try tweaking the sleep settings to find what does and doesn't work reliably.